# How to make datatableoutput resizing when dataframe becomes null

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinydashboard

I found a resizing problem in Shiny/Shinydashboard when a datatable changes from non-NULL to NULL.

Here a minimal example:

I define a reactive dataframe which can be switched using a checkbox from NULL to non-NULL.
A datatable is constructed from this dataframe and rendered in the UI.

Initially the dataframe is set to NULL. When the checkbox is unchecked the table is correctly popolated. Hoever, the datatable box is not correctly resized when when the checkbox is checked again.

Here the code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
### Server ###
server <- function(input, output, session){

test_df <- reactive({
if(input$ck_bx){
  NULL
}else{
  data.frame(A=1:20, B=2*1:20)
}
})

output$test_dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
datatable(test_df(), options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
})
}

### UI ###
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(checkboxInput("ck_bx",label="NULL: ", value = T),
dashboardBody(
  box(width=8,
dataTableOutput("test_dt")
)))

#### Run ####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)]
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: `if(input$ck_bx){NULL}` suggests that when the checkbox is checked, the data.frame becomes `NULL`. Perhaps you should be returning an empty data.frame instead

Comment: @waterling Thanks for the comment.
I didn't make myself clear:
the point is how to render correctly a datatable output when the dataframe become null, not how the dataframe is set to null.
I used the checkbox just to provide an example.

Comment: What does "correctly" mean? What sort of resizing are you expecting?

Comment: As you can see when you run the code:
1. the box containing the dataTable at the load (null dataframe) is only few px's high;
2.when the checkbox is unchecked (non-null dataframe) the box containing the dataTable adjust in height to the dataTable;
3. when the checkbox is checked again (null dataframe) the box height stays the same as at 2) and not resize to 1) as one should expects.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that even when the reactive is assigned to NULL, Shiny does not forget about the previous datatable, until it's overwritten by another datatable. If you look at the JS console, you can see that the `#test_dt` div is empty on app startup, then it gets populated by the table when the checkbox is unchecked for the first time. However, when you check it again, the content does not go away!

So, what you really need to do is not change the reactive, but rather hide the whole slot, independently if it has stuff on it or not. You can do this nicely by adding an observeEvent and using ShinyJS.

Here's the working example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(checkboxInput("ck_bx",label="NULL: ", value = T)),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    box(width=8, dataTableOutput("test_dt"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$ck_bx, {
    if (input$ck_bx) hide("test_dt")
    else show("test_dt")
  })

  test_df <- reactive({ data.frame(A=1:20, B=2*1:20) })

  output$test_dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(test_df(), options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @waterling suggested you could return an empty dataframe. I have updated your example with required changes. Note, you were also missing one braces in `ui`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
### Server ###
server <- function(input, output, session){

  test_df <- reactive({
    if(input$ck_bx){
      my_df <- data.frame(A=character(0), B=character(0))
    }else{
      my_df <- data.frame(A=1:20, B=2*1:20)
    }

    return(my_df)

  })

  output$test_dt <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(test_df(), options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  })
}

### UI ###
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(checkboxInput("ck_bx",label="NULL: ", value = T)),
  dashboardBody(box(width=8, dataTableOutput("test_dt"))))

#### Run ####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction in the code.
The point is not how the dataframe is set to null (here the checkbox is just an example to show the visualization problem), but rather if there is a way (options in datatable/shinyjs/etc..) to avoid having a (possibly large) white space if the dataframe form not-null becomes null.

Based on your answer i could do something like
`test_df_2 <- reactive({ifelse(is.null(test_df()), data.frame(A=character(0), B=character(0)), test_df())})`

but it seems a bit dirty. I was wondering if there is a way acting on datatable options or shinyjs.